# "somehow" or " in any way"?

Tags: phrases, phrase-choice

Tell me please which one of the following sentences sounds the most natural.

> Can I help you **somehow**?
>
> Can I help you **in any way**?

What I am trying to convey is a willingeness to know if there is a way I can be helpful.

Comment: Google Books Ngram Viewer indicates that the latter construction is many times more popular than the former. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=help+you+somehow%2Chelp+you+in+any+way

Comment: To me, neither sounds as good as simply saying, *Can I help you?*, without adding anything at the end at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Among your options I'd pick the latter as a good choice. Besides them, here are a few more options:

- Is there anything I can help you with?
- Can I help you with anything?
- Would you like me to help with anything?
- Is there any way I could be of assistance to you?
- Do you need any help?
- What is there I can help you with?
- Can I be of any assistance to you?

Answer (score 2):

"Can I help you in any way?" would be much more common.

Another variation which is perhaps more common (especially in a formal setting) would be:

> Can I help you at all?

"Can I help you somehow?" would be more suited to a casual setting, although would more likely be said as:

> Can I help?

You might also say:

> Can I help somehow?

Saying it like this expresses a certain curiosity in the process/workings of the thing you'd be helping with.